# Parse upload image UItableview

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"imageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSData *imageData =UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"inbox.png"]);
    PFObject *almacen = [_browserImagenes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFFile *archivo = almacen [@"image"];
    [archivo getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        }
    }];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: here what do you want, please explain clearly. do you want to load images asynchronously?

Comment: Yes. My images are store in Parse.com

Comment: So you want to display those images in tableview?

Comment: Yes.And the problem is that I can not see nothing

Comment: You used 'imagenArchivo', what it return image url?

Comment: I am sorry but I can not really write my code properly here. The system makes a lot of restriction to write all and I understand the just one part create confusion.

Comment: So, "archivo" is my PFFile from Parse.

Comment: @maytelabarga do you want to upload your image to parse.com? or want to display image from parse.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code in your UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method ...

PFFile *imageFile = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"yourColumnName"];

```
if (imageFile) {
    self.imageView.file = imageFile;
    [self.imageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
    }];
}
```

Comment: Use PFImageView for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign Downloaded image to UIImageView of Cell, which you forgot. I have modified your code as below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"imageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSData *imageData =UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"inbox.png"]);
    PFObject *almacen = [_browserImagenes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFFile *archivo = almacen [@"image"];
    [archivo getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            // *** Here you need to set image to imageview to display it ***
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        }
    }];


    return cell;
}
```